# Variable class creation

Tags: delphi

I want to minimize this code by using a variable class type and it's properties and events from:

```
if ctype='T' then
begin
  C:= TTimeEdit.Create(self);
  (c as TTimeEdit).OnMouseUp:= Panel2MouseUp;
  (c as TTimeEdit).OnMouseDown:= Panel2MouseDown;
  (c as TTimeEdit).OnMouseMove:= Panel2MouseMove;
  (c as TTimeEdit).PopupMenu:= PopupMenu1;
end;

if ctype='S' then
begin
  C:= TTabSheet.Create(self);
  (c as TTabSheet).OnMouseUp:= Panel2MouseUp;
  (c as TTabSheet).OnMouseDown:= Panel2MouseDown;
  (c as TTabSheet).OnMouseMove:= Panel2MouseMove;
  (c as TTabSheet).PopupMenu:= PopupMenu1;
end;
```

to look like this:

```
VAR VARCLS:TCLASS;
BEGIN
  if ctype='S' then
   VARCLS:=TTabSheet;
  if ctype='T' then
   VARCLS:=TTimeEdit;
  C:= VARCLS.Create(self);
  (c as VARCLS).OnMouseUp:= Panel2MouseUp;
  (c as VARCLS).OnMouseDown:= Panel2MouseDown;
  (c as VARCLS).OnMouseMove:= Panel2MouseMove;
  (c as VARCLS).PopupMenu:= PopupMenu1;
end;
```

Sure the code is much longer than this, but I used a sample!!

Comment: Use RTTI to a achieve this

Comment: And I want a pony :-) You really need to ask an actual question, not give a list of requirements. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck exactly?

Comment: if all classes have a common parent class, with all events from that class, like it seems is your case, just create a `procedure AssignEvents(const AObject: TWinControl);` and inside it set required events. no need to cast individually. For FMX you probably need TControl. Just a sample.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this:

If the classes have a common ancestor (very likely for VCL or FMX classes) then you can just use a `class of TAncestor` and create a specific instance of that class.

See: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Class_References#Constructors_and_Class_References

Let's assume you're using the VCL, it's nearly the same using FMX
There is a caveat, the events of `TControl` are protected, but we can use an interposer class to get around that.

```
type
  TMyClass = class of TControl;

//interposer class, makes events public;

TPublicControl = class(TControl)
public
  property OnMouseUp;     //a 'naked' property redeclares the existing
  property OnMouseDown;   //events and properties as public
  property OnMouseMove;
  property PopupMenu; 
end;

function CreateThing(Owner: TControl; MyType: TMyClass): TControl;
begin
  Result:= MyType.Create(Owner);
  TPublicControl(Result).OnMouseUp:= Panel2MouseUp;
  ....
end;
```

The routine does not have to know the type, to still return a specific created instance.

You call this routine like so:

```
var 
  MyEdit: TEdit;
begin
  MyEdit:= TEdit(CreateThing(Panel, TEdit));
```

The other method uses RTTI, but I would not recommend this, unless you're using objects that do not have a common ancestor.
If that's true for you, let me know and I'll expand the answer.